# ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in D:\Yatharth Files\wamp\www\index.php on line 121

Tags: php

***Why does this code throw an error?***

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['aca'])){
    header("location:Academic");
}elseif(isset($_POST['ed'])){
    header("location:EnjoyDev");
}elseif(isset($_POST['hb'])){
    header("location:Hoverboard");
}elseif(isset($_POST['lc'])){
    header("location:LiveChat");
}elseif(isset($_POST['mp']){
    header("location:myPro");
}elseif(isset($_POST['ym'])){
    header("location:YatMath");
}
?>
```

> LINE 121:  }elseif(isset($_POST['mp']){
>
> **I didn't miss any semicolons.**

Answer (score 2):

LINE 121:

```
}elseif(isset($_POST['mp']){
```

should be

```
} elseif( isset($_POST['mp']) ) {
```

Also, I would suggest that you make use of spaces to improve your codes' readability. You wouldn't have made this mistake then.

Comment: I used sublime and thought that it is reliable. But it actually missed a bracket! BTW, Thanks for your most precious time.